# Inner or Outer joins with Pivot query

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a query that pivots a rows into columns.  The rows only exist if values are present, e.g. there are no rows with the values represented by NULL

```
Object Field_id    value
1      1           value1
1      2           value2
1      3           value3
2      2           value4
```

And I create the output

```
Object  field1  field2  field3
1       value1  value2  value3
2               value4
```

using a query like

```
select * from 
    (
        select fs.field_name,  s.text_value, s.id_object 
          from custom_field_str s  , 
        (select  ad.id_field field_id, fd.name field_name, 
num_display_order display_order, ad.text_table_name catalogue_table, ad.num_lines 
           from catalogues c 
          inner join attribute_definitions ad on c.id_object = ad.id_object_type 
          inner join field_definitions fd on ad.id_field = fd.id_object 
          where c.id_object = 'cA1') fs 
        where fs.catalogue_table = 'custom_field_str' 
          and fs.field_id = s.id_field 
    )
pivot 
    ( max(text_value)  
for field_name IN ('field1' as  field1,'field2' as  field2,'field3' as  field3)  )
```

So my question is, should I be using an outer join in the join between custom_field_str and the derived table fs.  Or does the PIVOT not require a full set of results to build the output grid?

Answer (score 0):

This line: `where fs.field_id = s.id_field` makes that for each row in table `custom_field_str` 
must exist row in your derived table `fs`. So you could change your query to simple join-version, here is my try:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bccef/1)</sup>

```
select * from (
    select fd.name field_name, s.text_value, s.id_object 
      from custom_field_str s 
      join catalogues c on c.id_object = 'cA1'
      join attribute_definitions ad on ad.id_field = s.id_field 
       and c.id_object = ad.id_object_type and ad.text_table_name = 'custom_field_str'
      join field_definitions fd on ad.id_field = fd.id_object )
pivot (max(text_value) 
  for field_name in ('field1' as field1,'field2' as field2,'field3' as field3))
```

Comment: Thanks Ponder Stibbons.  I have 5 custom_field_* tables that I join to in a set of unions.  So I have used this format mostly for readability.